# Java PreparedStatement failing to execute MySQL Insert statement

Tags: sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm trying to use a PreparedStatement in Java to insert a new user into a database. I create a correctly formatted SQL statement, but for some reason an error is created at the call to executeUpdate();

```
DatabaseConnection dbconnection = DatabaseConnection.getInstance();
Connection con = dbconnection.getConnection();
PreparedStatement pstmt; // Prepare Statement automatically sanitizes inputs
    try {
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + USERNAME + ", " + PASSWORD_HASH + ", " + EMAIL + ") VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        pstmt.setString(1, username); // (these are parameters)
        pstmt.setString(2, passwordHash);
        pstmt.setString(3, email);

        System.out.println(pstmt.toString());

        int updateCount = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Updated: " + updateCount);

        if (updateCount == 0) return false;
        return true;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        return false;
    }
```

I've taken the SQL statement that gets printed out and copied and pasted it into terminal where I have a connection to the database open and it works fine (with the added ';').

I know this isn't working because the print statement after the executeUpdate() never gets printed. I'm using PreparedStatements elsewhere in my code to check if a user is in the database and those SELECT calls work fine with executeQuery().

Why is this failing?

EDIT: I printed out the stack trace and I'm getting the error that one of the fields of my table doesn't have a default value. This is true. There are more fields to the table that username/passwordHash/email, but why would does the request execute fine from terminal and not from Java? (I'm figuring that if I just assign default values that will get around this, but I want to see if there's another way.)

Stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'firstname' doesn't have a default value
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2734)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
at com.quizzine.database.UserData.createNewAccount(UserData.java:81)
at com.quizzine.login.CreateAccountServlet.doPost(CreateAccountServlet.java:50)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Comment: Yes, I'm positive I'm connected to the database. Normal SELECT queries work and return the correct results also using PreparedStatements.

Answer (score 0):

> I printed out the stack trace and I'm getting the error that one of the fields of my table doesn't have a default value. This is true. There are more fields to the table that username/passwordHash/email, but why would does the request execute fine from terminal and not from Java?

It is fine to just insert values into a subset of columns in a table as long as the columns that are left out are nullable or they have default values specified through `DEFAULT` constraint. Otherwise the insert statement is bound to fail irrespective of running it through a console or a `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'firstname' doesn't have a default value
```

the Exception means your column `firstname` has a `NOT NULL` constraint and you didn't give it a default value when create the table `TABLE_NAME`

you can solve this problem by doing these two methods,

method 1:

```
alter "TABEL_NAME" 
add a default value, such as '' to the column "firstname"
```

or method 2:

```
    pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + USERNAME + ", " + PASSWORD_HASH + ", " + EMAIL + ", " + FIRST_NAME + ") VALUES (?, ?, ?, '')");      // changed here
    pstmt.setString(1, username); // (these are parameters)
    pstmt.setString(2, passwordHash);
    pstmt.setString(3, email);
```